# Alphabetically sort a list of objects by member in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to create a function to sort a list of contacts in an address book by name or last name.

```
 void sortList (list<Contact> & address_book){

 //define two iterators - first to point to the first element from the list, second to the second element
 list<Contact>::iterator it = address_book.begin();
 list<Contact>::iterator it2 = address_book.begin();
 it2++;

 //get the last name for the first 2 contacts
 string last_name1 = it->get_last_name();
 string last_name2 = it2->get_last_name();

 int i = 0;

 while (i < last_name1.length() && i < last_name2.length()){

       if (last_name1[i] < last_name2[i]){
          swap(it, it2);
          break;
       }

 }
}
```

I'm sure I'm not doing it correctly, but I'm a little bit lost with these iterators. I also know I should have another while loop to loop through all my contacts until all of them are sorted but, honestly I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::list has an overloaded member function sort, that

> Sorts the elements in ascending order. The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved. The first version uses operator< to compare the elements, the second version uses the given comparison function comp.

To give the comparison function you can use **functors**:

```
struct sort_by_name {
  bool operator()(const Contact &a, const Contact &b)
  { return a.get_name() < b.get_name(); }
};
struct sort_by_last_name {
  bool operator()(const Contact &a, const Contact &b)
  { return a.get_last_name() < b.get_last_name(); }
};
```

or simpler **free functions**

```
bool cmp_by_name(const Contact &a, const Contact &b)
{ return a.get_name() < b.get_name(); }
bool cmp_by_last_name(const Contact &a, const Contact &b)
{ return a.get_last_name() < b.get_last_name(); }
```

and you call it either

```
 address_book.sort(sort_by_name());
 address_book.sort(sort_by_last_name());
```

or

```
 address_book.sort(cmp_by_name);
 address_book.sort(cmp_by_last_name);
```

the accessors get_name() and get_last_name() must be const.

Comment: These simpler functions worked like a charm. No errors what so ever. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Don't do your own sorting. Use `std::sort()`. You'll need to supply a custom comparator — something like this:

```
struct LastNameComp {
    bool operator()(const Contact& a, const Contact& b) const {
        return a.get_last_name() < b.get_last_name();
    }
}
⋮
std::sort(address_book.begin(), address_book.end(), LastNameComp());
```

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, you can do better:

```
std::sort(address_book.begin(), address_book.end(),
    [](const Contact& a, const Contact& b) {
        return a.get_last_name() < b.get_last_name();
    });
```

Comment: I get this error 24 `passing `const Contact' as `this' argument of std::string Contact::get_last_name()' discards qualifiers`

Comment: @Adrian: Your `get_last_name()` function should probably be declared const unless you have a really, really, *really* good reason not to: `std::string get_last_name() const { //....`

Comment: Followed the comments but still errors `no matching function for call to `sort(std::_List_iterator<Contact>, std::_List_iterator<Contact>, main(int, char**)::LastNameComp)' `

Comment: @Adrian: It might be because I forgot to make `LastNameComp::operator()` a const member function. I've amended my answer accordingly. I hope this fixes it for you. You might also (or instead) need to declare the struct outside the scope of a function, but I'm less sure of this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answers given using `std::lexicographical_compare` and lists internal sort.

```
    struct LastNameComp {
        bool operator()(const Contact& a, const Contact& b) {
            return std::lexicographical_compare(
               a.get_last_name().begin(), a.get_last_name().end(),
               b.get_last_name().begin(), b.get_last_name().end(),  
            );
        }
    };

    address_book.sort(LastNameComp());
```

Comment: forgive my nievity, but how is this better than operator< on strings?  I cant think lexcompare handles utf8 or something...